# Why my Intent is unable to call onHandleIntent(Intent intent) and notification method inside the IntentService class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, intentservice

I have two classes mainly MainActivity.java and GeofenceTransitionIntentService.java class that extends `IntentService`. This class is unreachable. I have tried to call this class by using intent from MainActivity.java class but couldn't able to invoke GeofenceTransitionIntentService class.Please help me in this.

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.deepdepindersingh.geofence;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
//import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Button mAddGeofencesButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAddGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addGeofencesButton);
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
        // Get the geofences used. Geofence data is hard coded in this sample.

        populateGeofenceList();

        // Kick off the request to build GoogleApiClient.
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        //test_sendNotification("notification from main");
    }



    private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeoFenceTransitionIntentService.class);

        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling addgeoFences()
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    // The GeofenceRequest object.
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    // A pending intent that that is reused when calling removeGeofences(). This
                    // pending intent is used to generate an intent when a matched geofence
                    // transition is observed.
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
            Toast.makeText(this, "Callback Executed and Intent send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(Status status) {
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Geofences Added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        } else {
            // Get the status code for the error and log it using a user-friendly message.
            String errorMessage = "Error Occured In main";
        }

    }
    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }
    public void populateGeofenceList() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {

            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                    // geofence.
                    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

                    // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            entry.getValue().latitude,
                            entry.getValue().longitude,
                            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )

                    // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                    // removed after this period of time.
                    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)

                    // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                    // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                    // Create the geofence.
                    .build());
        }
    }
    private void test_sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
                // to decode the Bitmap.
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

GeofenceTransitionIntentService.java

```
package com.example.deepdepindersingh.geofence;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Deep Depinder Singh on 9/10/2016.
 */
public class GeoFenceTransitionIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "gfservice";

    public GeoFenceTransitionIntentService(){
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Intent recieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
            if(geofencingEvent.hasError()){
                String errorMessage = "Error Occured";
            }
            int geoFencetransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

            if(geoFencetransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||geoFencetransition ==  Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT){
                List<Geofence> triggeringGeofence = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

                String geofenceTransitionDetail = geGeoFenceTransitionDetail(this, geoFencetransition, triggeringGeofence);
                // Send notification and log the transition details.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Notified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetail);
                Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetail);
            } else {
                // Log the error.
                Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geoFencetransition));
            }

    }


    private String geGeoFenceTransitionDetail(Context context, int geoFencetransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofence) {
       // String geoFenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geoFencetransition);

        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geoFencetransition);

        // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
        ArrayList triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofence) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }

    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
            default:
                return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
        }
    }
    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
                // to decode the Bitmap.
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Note: ***

***> My Manifest File Include Services and necessary permission and Main

> motive is to Invoke Notifications***

---

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.deepdepindersingh.geofence">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service android:name=".GeoFenceTransitionIntentService"></service>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Activity-main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.deepdepindersingh.geofence.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AddGeofences"
        android:id="@+id/addGeofencesButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="addGeofencesButtonHandler" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your manifest. Did you check the logcat for errors?

Comment: No errors in LogCat,I Think!! As I am Testing this app directly on Motto g

Comment: Better you post small & relevant code instead of posting entire class, that is distraction than help.

Comment: I dont know how to do that

Comment: Please teach me.....

Comment: Now i am launching app...new error occurred "could not identity launch activity: Default activity not found."

Comment: Where do you call `addGeofencesButtonHandler()`? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: wait I will Upload That file tooo

Comment: @David Wasser. I have Called directly from the layout file. I am Uploading that